# Does $f(x) = \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} e^{-xi}y(1-y)^{i-1}$ have a closed form?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Does $f(x) = \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} e^{-xi}y(1-y)^{i-1}$ have a closed form? $y$ is assumed to be in $[0,1]$ and $x >0$.

What I tried: I tried differentiating/integrating the function term by term to see whether those are something that can be calculated, but it seems that this method did not work.

Answer (score 6):

Observe
\begin{align}
f(x) = \frac{y}{1-y}\sum^\infty_{i=1} [e^{-x}(1-y)]^i 
\end{align}
then use geometric series.

Comment: (The case $y=1$ obviously has to be dealt with separately.)

Comment: @ClementC. Yes. I will leave it as an exercise. =)

Comment: ^ Seems pretty easy, at least: looking at the original form, $y=0$ gives $f(x)=\sum0$—am I right? (@ClementC.)

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor Yes, of course: for $y=0$, the infinite sum simplifies pretty easily (be slightly careful though -- there is still *one* non-zero term)

Comment: @ClementC. Which term is that?

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor $i=1$:
$e^{-x}\cdot 1\cdot 0^{i-1}= e^{-x}$ since $0^0 = 1$ by convention.

Comment: @ClementC. Huh. . . . I always thought $0^0$ was indeterminate.